# SSO Established between WSo2 IS 5.3 and WSo2 API Manager 2.2. Tenant users are not able to login to store and publisher

Tags: wso2

SSO established between wso2 identity server and wso2 api manager. Added API_Publisher and API_Store as a service provider in identity server.

Created 2 tenants in Identity server, as citizen.in and business.in and created users under those tenants. When i try to login to API-M Publisher with API-URL/Publisher the page redirects to Identity server for authentication but the authentication fails.

"Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again."

Also checked the users in the tenants are showing in OpenLDAP

Comment: what's the doc you followed? Did you configure the LDAP in both servers?

Comment: Yes, I pointed wso2 IS and wso2 API-M user-mgmt.xml file to same ldap. I have created tenants, users and roles in IS and it reflected in API-M.

Comment: did you give permissions (login, publish etc.) to the users?

Comment: Yes, i Idid. Below are the details will explain clearly what i have done. Logged in with super admin and created 3 users, one with subscriber, one with publisher and another with sub, pub and creator. With these 3 users am able to login publisher and store for API-M as SSO. Also i have created 2 tenants and created users and roles under those tenants but the users in these tenants are not able to login publisher and store for API-M for SSO

Comment: do you see any error logs in when the login fail?

Comment: No error logs from API-M side. 
IDM error says: 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-11-26 09:16:32,899]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode

Publisher login page error as "Application you are trying to access does not allow users from your organization. "

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not enabled `SaaS Application` option in the service providers you created.

[image]

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Identity+Server+as+IDP+for+SSO

Comment: Yeah I figured out and checked Saas Application and it was working fine. Thank you for help :)